# 64 Bit Complex Multiplier

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

This is the SystemVerilog code for 64 Bit Complex Multiplier

```
// 
// SystemVerilog Project for EL Component of DSDV
//  Author: Anudeep N Rao
//  USN: 1RV22LVS01
//
module cmultx64 

(

cmul_if if1

);

reg signed [63:0] ai_fifo1, ai_fifo2, ai_fifo3, ai_fifo4   ;

reg signed [63:0] ar_fifo1, ar_fifo2, ar_fifo3, ar_fifo4   ;

reg signed [63:0] bi_fifo1, bi_fifo2, bi_fifo3, br_fifo1, br_fifo2, br_fifo3 ;

  reg signed [63:0]  addcommon     ;

  reg signed [63:0]  addr, addi     ;

  reg signed [128:0] mult0, multr, multi, pr_int, pi_int  ;

  reg signed [128:0] common, commonr1, commonr2   ;

  always @(posedge if1.clk)

begin

ar_fifo1   <= if1.ar;

ar_fifo2  <= ar_fifo1;

ai_fifo1   <= if1.ai;

ai_fifo2  <= ai_fifo1;

br_fifo1   <= if1.br;

br_fifo2  <= br_fifo1;

br_fifo3 <= br_fifo2;

bi_fifo1   <= if1.bi;

bi_fifo2  <= bi_fifo1;

bi_fifo3 <= bi_fifo2;

end

// Common factor (ar ai) x bi, shared for the calculations of the real and imaginary final products



  always @(posedge if1.clk)

begin

addcommon <= ar_fifo1 - ai_fifo1;

  mult0     <= 128'($signed(addcommon * bi_fifo2));

common    <= mult0;

end

// Real product

//

  always @(posedge if1.clk)

begin

ar_fifo3   <= ar_fifo2;

ar_fifo4  <= ar_fifo3;

  addr     <= 64'($signed(br_fifo3 - bi_fifo3));

  multr    <= {128'($signed(addr * ar_fifo4))};

commonr1 <= common;

  pr_int   <= {128'($signed(multr + commonr1))};

end

// Imaginary product

//

  always @(posedge if1.clk)

begin

ai_fifo3   <= ai_fifo2;

ai_fifo4  <= ai_fifo3;

  addi     <= 64'($signed(br_fifo3 + bi_fifo3));

  multi    <= {128'($signed(addi * ai_fifo4))};

commonr2 <= common;

  pi_int   <= {128'($signed(multi + commonr2))};

end

assign if1.pr = pr_int;

assign if1.pi = pi_int;
// Assertion to check if the real product calculation is correct
assert property (@(posedge if1.clk) multr + commonr1 == pr_int)
    else $error("Real product calculation is incorrect");

// Assertion to check if the imaginary product calculation is correct
assert property (@(posedge if1.clk) multi + commonr2 == pi_int)
    else $error("Imaginary product calculation is incorrect");

// Assertion to check if the common factor calculation is correct
assert property (@(posedge if1.clk) addcommon * bi_fifo2 == common)
    else $error("Common factor calculation is incorrect");


endmodule // cmultx64
```

This the testbench I have been using :

```
// 
// SystemVerilog Project for EL Component of DSDV
//  Author: Anudeep N Rao
//  USN: 1RV22LVS01
//
class Packet;

  var rand signed [63:0] ar;
  var rand signed [63:0] br;
  var rand signed [63:0] ai;
  var rand signed [63:0] bi;
  bit signed [128:0]       pr;
  bit signed [128:0]        pi;

constraint nse {
    ar inside {[0:2**63-1]};
    ai inside {[0:2**63-1]};
    br inside {[0:2**63-1]};
    bi inside {[0:2**63-1]};
      }
  // Print contents of the data packet
  function void print(string tag="");
    $display ("T=%0t %s ar=0x%0h ai=0x%0h br=0x%0h bi=0x%0h pr=0x%0h pi=0x%0h", $time, tag, ar,ai,br,bi,pr,pi);
    $display ("T=%0t %s ar=0x%0d ai=0x%0d br=0x%0d bi=0x%0d pr=0x%0d pi=0x%0d", $time, tag, ar,ai,br,bi,pr,pi);
  
  endfunction

  // This is a utility function to allow copying contents in
  // one Packet variable to another.
  function void copy(Packet tmp);
    this.ar = tmp.ar;
    this.ai = tmp.ai;
    this.br = tmp.br;
    this.bi = tmp.bi;
    this.pr = tmp.pr;
    this.pi = tmp.pi;
  endfunction
endclass

class driver;
  virtual cmul_if m_cmul_vif;
 
  event drv_done;
  mailbox drv_mbx;

  task run();
    $display ("T=%0t [Driver] starting ...", $time);

    // Try to get a new transaction every time and then assign
    // packet contents to the interface. But do this only if the
    // design is ready to accept new transactions
    forever begin
      Packet item;

      $display ("T=%0t [Driver] waiting for item ...", $time);
      drv_mbx.get(item);
      @ (posedge m_cmul_vif.clk);
          item.print("Driver");
     
      m_cmul_vif.ar <= item.ar;
      m_cmul_vif.ai <= item.ai;
      m_cmul_vif.br <= item.br;
      m_cmul_vif.bi <= item.bi;
      
      ->drv_done;
    end
  endtask
endclass

class monitor;
  virtual cmul_if      m_cmul_vif;
  

  mailbox scb_mbx;              // Mailbox connected to scoreboard

  task run();
    $display ("T=%0t [Monitor] starting ...", $time);

    // Check forever at every clock edge to see if there is a
    // valid transaction and if yes, capture info into a class
    // object and send it to the scoreboard when the transaction
    // is over.
    forever begin
          Packet m_pkt = new();
      @(posedge m_cmul_vif.clk);
      #1;
        m_pkt.ar         = m_cmul_vif.ar;
        m_pkt.ai         = m_cmul_vif.ai;
        m_pkt.br         = m_cmul_vif.br;
        m_pkt.bi         = m_cmul_vif.bi;
       // m_pkt.reset      = m_cmul_vif.reset;
        m_pkt.pr       = m_cmul_vif.pr;
        m_pkt.pi = m_cmul_vif.pi;
        m_pkt.print("Monitor");
      scb_mbx.put(m_pkt);
    end
  endtask
endclass

class scoreboard;
  mailbox scb_mbx;
  bit [63:0]ar_fifo[7];
  bit [63:0]ai_fifo[7];
  bit [63:0]br_fifo[7];
  bit [63:0]bi_fifo[7];
  

  task run();
    forever begin
      Packet item, ref_item;
      scb_mbx.get(item);
      item.print("Scoreboard");

      // Copy contents from received packet into a new packet so
      // just to get a and b.
      ref_item = new();
      ref_item.copy(item);
      for(int i=6;i>=0;i--)
      begin
        if(i) begin
            ar_fifo[i]<=ar_fifo[i-1];
            ai_fifo[i]<=ai_fifo[i-1];
            br_fifo[i]<=br_fifo[i-1];
            bi_fifo[i]<=bi_fifo[i-1];
            end
        if(i==0)begin
            ar_fifo[i]<=ref_item.ar;
            ai_fifo[i]<=ref_item.ai;
            br_fifo[i]<=ref_item.br;
            bi_fifo[i]<=ref_item.bi;
            end
            
      end

      // Let us calculate the expected values in pi and pr
      
      
      ref_item.pr = {ar_fifo[5]*br_fifo[5]} - {ai_fifo[5]*bi_fifo[5]};
      ref_item.pi = {ai_fifo[5]*br_fifo[5]} + {ar_fifo[5]*bi_fifo[5]};
      
      
      // Now, pi and pr outputs in the reference variable can be compared
      // with those in the received packet
      if (ref_item.pi != item.pi) begin
        $display("[%0t] Scoreboard Error! pi mismatch ref_item=0x%0h item=0x%0h", $time, ref_item.pi, item.pi);
      end else begin
        $display("[%0t] Scoreboard Pass! pi match ref_item=0x%0h item =0x%0h", $time, ref_item.pi, item.pi);
      end

      if (ref_item.pr != item.pr) begin
        $display("[%0t] Scoreboard Error! pr mismatch ref_item=0x%0h item=0x%0h", $time, ref_item.pr, item.pr);
      end else begin
        $display("[%0t] Scoreboard Pass! pr match ref_item=0x%0h item=0x%0h", $time, ref_item.pr, item.pr);
      end
    end
  endtask
endclass

class generator;
  int   loop = 10;
  event drv_done;
  mailbox drv_mbx;

  task run();
    for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) begin
      Packet item = new;
      item.randomize();
      
      $display ("T=%0t [Generator] Loop:%0d/%0d create next item", $time, i+1, loop);
      drv_mbx.put(item);
      $display ("T=%0t [Generator] Wait for driver to be done", $time);
      @(drv_done);
    end
  endtask
endclass

class env;  
  generator             g0; // Generate transactions         
  driver                        d0;                   // Driver to design  
  monitor                       m0;                    // Monitor from design
  scoreboard            s0;                     // Scoreboard connected to monitor
  mailbox                       scb_mbx;                // Top level mailbox for SCB <-> MON
  virtual cmul_if      m_cmul_vif;    // Virtual interface handle


  event drv_done;
  mailbox drv_mbx;

  function new();
    d0 = new;
    m0 = new;
    s0 = new;
    scb_mbx = new();
    g0 = new;
    drv_mbx = new;
  endfunction

  virtual task run();
    // Connect virtual interface handles
    d0.m_cmul_vif = m_cmul_vif;
    m0.m_cmul_vif = m_cmul_vif;
  

    // Connect mailboxes between each component
    d0.drv_mbx = drv_mbx;
    g0.drv_mbx = drv_mbx;

    m0.scb_mbx = scb_mbx;
    s0.scb_mbx = scb_mbx;

    // Connect event handles
    d0.drv_done = drv_done;
    g0.drv_done = drv_done;

    // Start all components - a fork join_any is used because
    // the stimulus is generated by the generator and we want the
    // simulation to exit only when the generator has finished
    // creating all transactions. Until then all other components
    // have to run in the background.
    fork
        s0.run();
                d0.run();
        m0.run();
        g0.run();
    join_any
  endtask
endclass

interface cmul_if();
 
  logic                 clk;
 
  logic [63:0]      ar;
  logic [63:0]      ai;
  logic [63:0]      br;
  logic [63:0]      bi;
  logic [128:0]         pr;
  logic [128:0]         pi;
  initial clk <= 0;
 

  always #10 clk = ~clk;
endinterface

class test;
  env e0;
  mailbox drv_mbx;

  function new();
    drv_mbx = new();
    e0 = new();
  endfunction

  virtual task run();
    e0.d0.drv_mbx = drv_mbx;
    e0.run();
  endtask
endclass

module tb;

  bit tb_clk;

  
  cmul_if      m_cmul_if();
  cmultx64      m0          (m_cmul_if);

  initial begin
    test t0;
    t0 = new;
    t0.e0.m_cmul_vif = m_cmul_if;
   
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
  $dumpvars;
    t0.run();
    #50 $finish;
  end
  // Define a covergroup
  covergroup cmultx64_cg @(posedge m_cmul_if.clk);
  // Coverpoints
  coverpoint m_cmul_if.ar { bins low = {0}; bins high = {64'h7FFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF}; }
  coverpoint m_cmul_if.ai { bins low = {0}; bins high = {64'h7FFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF}; }
  coverpoint m_cmul_if.br { bins low = {0}; bins high = {64'h7FFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF}; }
  coverpoint m_cmul_if.bi { bins low = {0}; bins high = {64'h7FFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF}; }

  // Cross coverage: This will give us a matrix of all possible combinations of ar, ai, br, bi
  cross m_cmul_if.ar, m_cmul_if.ai, m_cmul_if.br, m_cmul_if.bi;
endgroup

// Instantiate the covergroup
cmultx64_cg cg1;

initial begin
  // Initialize the covergroup
  cg1 = new();
end

  always @(posedge m_cmul_if.clk) begin
  // Sample the covergroup
  cg1.sample();
end
  endmodule
```

The output is :

```
T=131 Monitor ar=0x3663928677917193535 ai=0x7890384334432080575 br=0x518813531089504302 bi=0x7052919361153373150 pr=0x135810663822377906 pi=0x10266323930858106324
# T=131 Scoreboard ar=0x32d8e3b8619ef53f ai=0x6d8046bf432192bf br=0x73332286141882e bi=0x61e100ca7f0593de pr=0x1e27f1445d7c3b2 pi=0x8e794f38c7e3add4
# T=131 Scoreboard ar=0x3663928677917193535 ai=0x7890384334432080575 br=0x518813531089504302 bi=0x7052919361153373150 pr=0x135810663822377906 pi=0x10266323930858106324
# [131] Scoreboard Pass! pi match ref_item=0x8e794f38c7e3add4 item =0x8e794f38c7e3add4
# [131] Scoreboard Pass! pr match ref_item=0x1e27f1445d7c3b2 item=0x1e27f1445d7c3b2
# T=150 Driver ar=0x737b139455d25390 ai=0x744cef14d0239552 br=0xe61f0f2107efd2e bi=0x124db73361155bbb pr=0x0 pi=0x0
# T=150 Driver ar=0x8321266264313058192 ai=0x8380335879300027730 br=0x1036374311721434414 bi=0x1318911697189428155 pr=0x0 pi=0x0
# T=150 [Driver] waiting for item ...
# T=150 [Generator] Loop:9/10 create next item
# T=150 [Generator] Wait for driver to be done
# ** Error: Common factor calculation is incorrect
#    Time: 150 ns Started: 150 ns  Scope: tb.m0 File: C:/Users/Anudeep/Desktop/doc_temp/SV_EL/cmultx64.sv Line: 127
# ** Error: Imaginary product calculation is incorrect
#    Time: 150 ns Started: 150 ns  Scope: tb.m0 File: C:/Users/Anudeep/Desktop/doc_temp/SV_EL/cmultx64.sv Line: 123
# ** Error: Real product calculation is incorrect
#    Time: 150 ns Started: 150 ns  Scope: tb.m0 File: C:/Users/Anudeep/Desktop/doc_temp/SV_EL/cmultx64.sv Line: 119
# T=151 Monitor ar=0x737b139455d25390 ai=0x744cef14d0239552 br=0xe61f0f2107efd2e bi=0x124db73361155bbb pr=0x7608a64d5f26d1ec pi=0xfffffffffffffffff9c59515add5b864
# T=151 Monitor ar=0x8321266264313058192 ai=0x8380335879300027730 br=0x1036374311721434414 bi=0x1318911697189428155 pr=0x8505230747528253932 pi=0x340282366920938463462925818764258031716
# T=151 Scoreboard ar=0x737b139455d25390 ai=0x744cef14d0239552 br=0xe61f0f2107efd2e bi=0x124db73361155bbb pr=0x7608a64d5f26d1ec pi=0xfffffffffffffffff9c59515add5b864
# T=151 Scoreboard ar=0x8321266264313058192 ai=0x8380335879300027730 br=0x1036374311721434414 bi=0x1318911697189428155 pr=0x8505230747528253932 pi=0x340282366920938463462925818764258031716
# [151] Scoreboard Error! pi mismatch ref_item=0xf9c59515add5b864 item=0xfffffffffffffffff9c59515add5b864
# [151] Scoreboard Pass! pr match ref_item=0x7608a64d5f26d1ec item=0x7608a64d5f26d1ec
# T=170 Driver ar=0xd27934d8c819661 ai=0x2aff7bc8688b9785 br=0x2fa6f58da3a7dbb3 bi=0xbe7f758685c0d87 pr=0x0 pi=0x0
# T=170 Driver ar=0x947888207863846497 ai=0x3098331169331844997 br=0x3433701754601462707 bi=0x857926213117414791 pr=0x0 pi=0x0
# T=170 [Driver] waiting for item ...
# T=170 [Generator] Loop:10/10 create next item
# T=170 [Generator] Wait for driver to be done
# ** Error: Common factor calculation is incorrect
#    Time: 170 ns Started: 170 ns  Scope: tb.m0 File: C:/Users/Anudeep/Desktop/doc_temp/SV_EL/cmultx64.sv Line: 127
# ** Error: Imaginary product calculation is incorrect
#    Time: 170 ns Started: 170 ns  Scope: tb.m0 File: C:/Users/Anudeep/Desktop/doc_temp/SV_EL/cmultx64.sv Line: 123
# ** Error: Real product calculation is incorrect
#    Time: 170 ns Started: 170 ns  Scope: tb.m0 File: C:/Users/Anudeep/Desktop/doc_temp/SV_EL/cmultx64.sv Line: 119
# T=171 Monitor ar=0xd27934d8c819661 ai=0x2aff7bc8688b9785 br=0x2fa6f58da3a7dbb3 bi=0xbe7f758685c0d87 pr=0xb87927d662a297b pi=0x28c010765c8cf339
# T=171 Monitor ar=0x947888207863846497 ai=0x3098331169331844997 br=0x3433701754601462707 bi=0x857926213117414791 pr=0x830793723555752315 pi=0x2936365057590489913
# T=171 Scoreboard ar=0xd27934d8c819661 ai=0x2aff7bc8688b9785 br=0x2fa6f58da3a7dbb3 bi=0xbe7f758685c0d87 pr=0xb87927d662a297b pi=0x28c010765c8cf339
# T=171 Scoreboard ar=0x947888207863846497 ai=0x3098331169331844997 br=0x3433701754601462707 bi=0x857926213117414791 pr=0x830793723555752315 pi=0x2936365057590489913
# [171] Scoreboard Error! pi mismatch ref_item=0x128c010765c8cf339 item=0x28c010765c8cf339
# [171] Scoreboard Pass! pr match ref_item=0xb87927d662a297b item=0xb87927d662a297b
# T=190 Driver ar=0xb1a0f6fdf759c97 ai=0x393a0e9c7d5cc062 br=0x68dfde48de03535a bi=0x1b3f115e4c0807cc pr=0x0 pi=0x0
# T=190 Driver ar=0x799968856976497815 ai=0x4123624474092028002 br=0x7557003104294753114 bi=0x1963307059257018316 pr=0x0 pi=0x0
# T=190 [Driver] waiting for item ...
# ** Error: Common factor calculation is incorrect
#    Time: 190 ns Started: 190 ns  Scope: tb.m0 File: C:/Users/Anudeep/Desktop/doc_temp/SV_EL/cmultx64.sv Line: 127
# ** Error: Imaginary product calculation is incorrect
#    Time: 190 ns Started: 190 ns  Scope: tb.m0 File: C:/Users/Anudeep/Desktop/doc_temp/SV_EL/cmultx64.sv Line: 123
# ** Error: Real product calculation is incorrect
#    Time: 190 ns Started: 190 ns  Scope: tb.m0 File: C:/Users/Anudeep/Desktop/doc_temp/SV_EL/cmultx64.sv Line: 119
# T=191 Monitor ar=0xb1a0f6fdf759c97 ai=0x393a0e9c7d5cc062 br=0x68dfde48de03535a bi=0x1b3f115e4c0807cc pr=0x2e7bedf58d282440 pi=0xb0e57e7cabfe6610
# T=191 Monitor ar=0x799968856976497815 ai=0x4123624474092028002 br=0x7557003104294753114 bi=0x1963307059257018316 pr=0x3349532386771084352 pi=0x12746733394268677648
# T=191 Scoreboard ar=0xb1a0f6fdf759c97 ai=0x393a0e9c7d5cc062 br=0x68dfde48de03535a bi=0x1b3f115e4c0807cc pr=0x2e7bedf58d282440 pi=0xb0e57e7cabfe6610
# T=191 Scoreboard ar=0x799968856976497815 ai=0x4123624474092028002 br=0x7557003104294753114 bi=0x1963307059257018316 pr=0x3349532386771084352 pi=0x12746733394268677648
# [191] Scoreboard Pass! pi match ref_item=0xb0e57e7cabfe6610 item =0xb0e57e7cabfe6610
# [191] Scoreboard Error! pr mismatch ref_item=0x1ffffffffffffffff2e7bedf58d282440 item=0x2e7bedf58d282440
# ** Error: Common factor calculation is incorrect
#    Time: 210 ns Started: 210 ns  Scope: tb.m0 File: C:/Users/Anudeep/Desktop/doc_temp/SV_EL/cmultx64.sv Line: 127
# ** Error: Imaginary product calculation is incorrect
#    Time: 210 ns Started: 210 ns  Scope: tb.m0 File: C:/Users/Anudeep/Desktop/doc_temp/SV_EL/cmultx64.sv Line: 123
# ** Error: Real product calculation is incorrect
#    Time: 210 ns Started: 210 ns  Scope: tb.m0 File: C:/Users/Anudeep/Desktop/doc_temp/SV_EL/cmultx64.sv Line: 119
# T=211 Monitor ar=0xb1a0f6fdf759c97 ai=0x393a0e9c7d5cc062 br=0x68dfde48de03535a bi=0x1b3f115e4c0807cc pr=0xffffffffffffffffdd8ae577b584733b pi=0xffffffffffffffff5381f455a77ce0dd
# T=211 Monitor ar=0x799968856976497815 ai=0x4123624474092028002 br=0x7557003104294753114 bi=0x1963307059257018316 pr=0x340282366920938463460891687489536029499 pi=0x340282366920938463450945222583921729757
# T=211 Scoreboard ar=0xb1a0f6fdf759c97 ai=0x393a0e9c7d5cc062 br=0x68dfde48de03535a bi=0x1b3f115e4c0807cc pr=0xffffffffffffffffdd8ae577b584733b pi=0xffffffffffffffff5381f455a77ce0dd
# T=211 Scoreboard ar=0x799968856976497815 ai=0x4123624474092028002 br=0x7557003104294753114 bi=0x1963307059257018316 pr=0x340282366920938463460891687489536029499 pi=0x340282366920938463450945222583921729757
# [211] Scoreboard Error! pi mismatch ref_item=0x15381f455a77ce0dd item=0xffffffffffffffff5381f455a77ce0dd
# [211] Scoreboard Error! pr mismatch ref_item=0xdd8ae577b584733b item=0xffffffffffffffffdd8ae577b584733b
# ** Error: Common factor calculation is incorrect
#    Time: 230 ns Started: 230 ns  Scope: tb.m0 File: C:/Users/Anudeep/Desktop/doc_temp/SV_EL/cmultx64.sv Line: 127
# ** Error: Imaginary product calculation is incorrect
#    Time: 230 ns Started: 230 ns  Scope: tb.m0 File: C:/Users/Anudeep/Desktop/doc_temp/SV_EL/cmultx64.sv Line: 123
# ** Error: Real product calculation is incorrect
#    Time: 230 ns Started: 230 ns  Scope: tb.m0 File: C:/Users/Anudeep/Desktop/doc_temp/SV_EL/cmultx64.sv Line: 119
# T=231 Monitor ar=0xb1a0f6fdf759c97 ai=0x393a0e9c7d5cc062 br=0x68dfde48de03535a bi=0x1b3f115e4c0807cc pr=0xffffffffffffffffcf4181621a71ecc1 pi=0x2e2aaa4d10ff1f50
# T=231 Monitor ar=0x799968856976497815 ai=0x4123624474092028002 br=0x7557003104294753114 bi=0x1963307059257018316 pr=0x340282366920938463459862223455746387137 pi=0x3326658522740891472
# T=231 Scoreboard ar=0xb1a0f6fdf759c97 ai=0x393a0e9c7d5cc062 br=0x68dfde48de03535a bi=0x1b3f115e4c0807cc pr=0xffffffffffffffffcf4181621a71ecc1 pi=0x2e2aaa4d10ff1f50
# T=231 Scoreboard ar=0x799968856976497815 ai=0x4123624474092028002 br=0x7557003104294753114 bi=0x1963307059257018316 pr=0x340282366920938463459862223455746387137 pi=0x3326658522740891472
# [231] Scoreboard Error! pi mismatch ref_item=0x12e2aaa4d10ff1f50 item=0x2e2aaa4d10ff1f50
# [231] Scoreboard Error! pr mismatch ref_item=0x1ffffffffffffffffcf4181621a71ecc1 item=0xffffffffffffffffcf4181621a71ecc1
# ** Note: $finish    : C:/Users/Anudeep/Desktop/doc_temp/SV_EL/top.sv(276)
#    Time: 240 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /tb
# 1
```

What could be the problem. Coverage of covergroups were very low (6%). This code is a part of experiential learning for university course. This EL project presents the design and verification of a 64-bit Complex Multiplication Unit (CMU) using System Verilog. The CMU, designed to process two complex numbers in cartesian form, outputs the real and imaginary parts of their product. The unit leverages a pipelined architecture for high throughput and low latency. Verification of the CMU’s functionality is performed using a System Verilog test environment, which generates random inputs and validates the outputs against a reference model. This work demonstrates an efficient method for high-speed complex number multiplication, with potential applications in digital signal processing and control systems.

Comment: See [cmul](https://docs.xilinx.com/v/u/2019.2-English/ug901-vivado-synthesis)  page 93 for working examples of complex multipliers written in verilog.  You can use the code, or reference is for style guidance.  Maybe looking at what they have done will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Issues:

1. the number of bits used for addition (subtraction) is wrong in at least one place.
   For example this line
   `addcommon <= ar_fifo1 - ai_fifo1;`
   subtracts 64 bits from 64 bits and assigns the value into 64 bits.
   The result needs to be 65 bits to hold the addition(subtraction).
   The code may have the same error in multiple places (wherever you add or subtract).
   Check each addition(subtraction) in the code for the same error.
   The result of the addition size change may propagate into more terms so the size of those terms may need to be adjusted also.

Here is a reference for bit growth in fpga arithmetic [bit-growth](https://zipcpu.com/dsp/2017/07/21/bit-growth.html).

2. The interface outputs pr, pi are defined as logic which is unsigned.  Make them signed to have signed outputs.

The code hard to follow.  One reason is that you have not provided the algorithm is being used.  It would be easier to follow if you provided the recipe and had simple variable names which matched the algorithm.  Here is an example of what I would post in the question:

"I am trying to implement this equation"

[image]

That image was taken from here: [Example](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexMultiplication.html).

I am not saying that you need to use that equation,  I am saying that you don't state what equation you are implementing , and express that  in the code, using simple variable names as was done in the example (a,b,c,d).  That would make the code easier to debug and verify the intermediate quantities.

If that were the case (if the recipe were clear and the code used easy to follow variable names used in the recipe), then start by checking values of the intermediate results.  For example are the intermediate multiplies a*c and b*d correct?  If its hard to determine what intermediate values are expected to be, it will be very hard to determine if they are correct.